Blueberry cuttings - inert medium or no?
I have a group of cuttings from 4 different blueberry bushes on my recently-late grandmother's property. I'm trying to save some of her plants before the property is sold.
I'm looking at different instructions and YouTube videos on what kind of substrate is best to root them in. Some use a peat moss-based medium, some go straight for sand and something completely inert so as to inhibit fungal/bacterial growth.
I currently have the cuttings in a mixture of sphagnum peat moss, coconut fiber, perlite and vermiculite. Rooting powder at the bottom & underground nodes. They've been like that for about a week, I'd say. In one pot, some of the leaves are browning at the tips, but I'm told that's normal. Recently I put gallon bags over them as humidity tents because I didn't realize the leaves needed to be moist. Everything else looks healthy. Are they fine as they are right now or should I move them into something more sterile?

Bottom heat with a heating pad will help a lot!
